# The command basename don't work in find command

Tags: bash, find, basename

The output of:

```
find mydir -name foo -exec echo "---$(basename {})---" \;
```

should be **---foo---**, but instead it is **---mydir/foo---**

The command **basename** alone:

```
basename mydir/foo 
echo "---$(basename mydir/foo)---"
```

brings respective **foo** and **---foo---**

Replacing ***basename*** with other command such as ***uname*** the construct $(...) works correct.

Answer (score 4):

Because `$(basename {})` gets expanded to `{}` by bash before running `find` command, your `find` command is exactly equivalent to :

```
find mydir -name foo -exec echo "---{}---" \;
```

That's why you see `---mydir/foo---`

To get the effect you wanted, you can do :

```
find mydir -name foo -exec bash -c 'echo "---$(basename {})---"' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found a solution by creating a script that calls itself from the find command:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    find myDir -name foo -exec $(readlink -f $0) "{}" \;
else
    echo "---$(basename $1)---"
fi
```

It's not as elegant as one line solution (hat tip to Phillipe) but if necessary more expandable